# How to get DateTime with a UTC datetime and a particular timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, datetimeoffset

My data in SQL database  looks like this:

```
PubDateUTC              PubDateUTCOffset
----------------------- --------------------
2011-08-04 10:02:50.000 +8:00:00
2012-04-23 02:32:25.287 +8:00:00
2010-09-26 04:23:00.000 +8:00:00
```

What I want is to get a DateTime based on **PubDateUTC** and **PubDateUTCOffset**, for example:

**2011-08-04 10:02:50.000, +8:00:00** should result in **2011-08-04 18:02:50:000**

I have tried with TimeZoneInfo class, but I don't know hot to create a instance of TimeZoneInfo with a string like "+8:00:00", which would be the CreateTimeZoneInfo method below

```
var tz = CreateTimeZoneInfo(post.PubDateUTCOffset);
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(post.PubDateUTC, tz);
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Note: I cannot change the data in SQL database.

Comment: Save the dates as DateTimeOffset in database this is very helpfull shall I write for you an example! or you cannot do that now

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the database design :(

Comment: Is your goal to get the local time ? Or the local time in the timezone specified by the offset ? Or some other timezone ?

Comment: Should "2011-08-04 10:02:50.000, +8:00:00" actually result in "2011-08-04 2:02:50:000"?  This is the equivalent time in GMT.

Comment: Had the same thought as Leonid, are you sure the result you are asking for is the right one.

Comment: @LeonidTsybert - the value in the db is *already* in UTC/GMT.  If it was stored as `datetimeoffset` then it would be `2011-08-04T18:02:50.000+08:00`, but since it is stored at UTC then the offset applies in the other direction to get back to local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var date = post.PubDateUTC.Add(
                TimeSpan.Parse(post.PubDateUTCOffset.Replace("+", ""))
           );
```

The `.Replace("+", "")` is because `TimeSpan` will handle `-01:00:00` but will choke on `+01:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use DateTimeOffset class. This thread may be helpful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works, remove any leading "+" from the offset ( "-" are ok)

```
var d = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Parse("2011-08-04 10:02:50.000"), 
                           TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00"));
```

- d.DateTime - the time in db = 10:02:50
- d.LocalDateTime - the time according to your servers timezone
- d.UtcDateTime - the time at GMT = 02:02:50

I'm not sure you want 18:02:50 since it is the time at GMT+16 (+16:00:00), unless of course that is how it's encoded in the db, then just ignore this post :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `post` class to have one property:

```
public DateTimeOffset Published { get; set; }
```

Then when you read from the database (assuming you have `datetime` and `varchar` types in your database):

```
DateTime utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
                       (DateTime) reader["PubDateUTC"], DateTimeKind.Utc);

TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.Parse(
                       ((string) reader["PubDateUTCOffset"]).Replace("+", ""))

post.Published = new DateTimeOffset(utc).ToOffset(offset);
```

Then when you need to consume it, you have all of the options of a full `DateTimeOffset`:

```
DateTime local = post.Published.DateTime;  // with your offset applied

DateTime utc = post.Published.UtcDateTime; // the original utc value

string s = post.Published.ToString("o");   //  2011-08-04T18:02:50.0000000+08:00
```